# Is a workshop experience relevant for graduate school?

Tags: resume

Do grad schools consider workshop experience even if it's only for 1-2 weeks?

If an applicant has this experience, do they even care?

Comment: Did you attend a workshop? Did you teach at the workshop? Did you organize the workshop?

Comment: i attend the workshop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Academia SE.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace! Could you add some detail to your question? What is a "workshop"? What kind of graduate school are you interested in? Where are you disclosing your workshop participation (e.g., resume, interview)?

Comment: I would think so. I suggest you move this to academia.stackexchange.com because that community seems closer to your target audience.

Comment: @thedude What sort of workshop and which country are you from  in standard English "workshop experience" might mean you worked in a  carpentry or machine tool workshop.

Answer (score 2):

Any relevant experience is exactly that. Experience that is relevant, therefore grad schools will take it into account. If they have two candidates exactly the same, and one shows the initiative to attend workshops and gain extra knowledge. Then obviously the pick is made simple.

I'm not saying it's guaranteeing you a place, but it can definitely work in your favour.